# More efficiently access iterator values in subkernels?

Tags: performance-tuning, procedural-programming, monitoring

I'm looking for more efficient ways of observing values in loops in subkernels. For example, take a standard `Do` loop:

```
AbsoluteTiming[s = 0; Do[s += j, {j, 10^7}];] (* ~3.7s *)
```

One way to access the iterator's value would be `Monitor`, which adds a tiny bit of overhead:

```
AbsoluteTiming[i = 0; s = 0; Monitor[Do[s += j, {j, 10^7}], i = j]] (* ~3.9s *)
```

However you don't *actually have a variable* and you lose the observation when it completes, so that's not what we want.

The other obvious thing is using either an (atomic) increment or assignment, ok, but that *about doubles the time*:

```
AbsoluteTiming[i = 0; s = 0; Do[s += j; i++, {j, 10^7}]]   (* ~7.3s *)
AbsoluteTiming[i = 0; s = 0; Do[s += j; i = j, {j, 10^7}]] (* ~7.4s *)
```

You can't update once in a while either as that logic adds overhead:

```
AbsoluteTiming[i = 0; s = 0; 
    Do[s += j; If[Mod[j, 10000] == 0, i = j], {j, 10^7}]]  (* ~13.0s *)
```

Things become worse in parallel code:

```
LaunchKernels[4]; AbsoluteTiming[WaitAll @ Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, 
    s = 0; Do[s+=j, {j, 1, i}]; s], {i, Table[10^6.5, 8]}];] (* 4.72s *)
```

As soon as you maintain access to the iterator values everything melts down:

```
$monitor = <|1->0,2->0,3->0,4->0|>; SetSharedVariable[$monitor]; 
Dynamic[$monitor, UpdateInterval->1]
AbsoluteTiming[
   WaitAll @ Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, s = 0; Do[
        AssociateTo[$monitor,  (* iterator access massive slowdown *)
           Mod[$KernelID, $KernelCount]+1 -> j]; 
        s += j, {j, 1, i}]; s]
        , {i, Table[10^6.5, 8]}];
] (* ...minutes *)
```

Are there any tricks/patterns to avoid slowdowns when you need to keep a handle on iterator values inside such looping constructs?

Comment: "You can't update once in a while either, because duh, that logic adds overhead:" That's true, but in parallel computations, only the local overhead is increased. But the crucial one there is the global one and that is significantly decreased this way.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm getting at, just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by *observing*, but if you want to view the iteration variable, then you probably want to check out this behavior of Mathematica 12 (under Mac):

````
Dynamic[i]
AbsoluteTiming[Do[i, {i, 10^7}]]
(* {0.615904, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[j, {j, 10^7}]]
(* {0.586199, Null} *)
```
````

Comment: Ah, but usually my loops are within ParallelSubmit's, so they are running in subkernels - I should have made that clear

Comment: Updated the problem. Do you have a way of using dynamics across subkernels?